# Pyspark create temp view from dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read thorugh spark.sql a huge csv.
I created a dataframe from a CSV, the dataframe seems created correctly.
I read the schema and I can perform select and filter.
I would like to create a temp view to execute same research using sql, I am more comfortable with it but the temp view seems created on the csv header only.
Where am I making the mistake?
Thanks

```
>>> df = spark.read.options(header=True,inferSchema=True,delimiter=";").csv("./elenco_dm_tutti_csv_formato_opendata_UltimaVersione.csv")
>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- TIPO: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- PROGRESSIVO_DM_ASS: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- DATA_PRIMA_PUBBLICAZIONE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DM_RIFERIMENTO: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- GRUPPO_DM_SIMILI: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- ISCRIZIONE_REPERTORIO: string (nullable = true)
 |-- INIZIO_VALIDITA: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FINE_VALIDITA: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FABBRICANTE_ASSEMBLATORE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CODICE_FISCALE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PARTITA_IVA_VATNUMBER: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CODICE_CATALOGO_FABBR_ASS: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DENOMINAZIONE_COMMERCIALE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CLASSIFICAZIONE_CND: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DESCRIZIONE_CND: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DATAFINE_COMMERCIO: string (nullable = true)

>>> df.count()
1653697
>>> df.createOrReplaceTempView("mask")
>>> spark.sql("select count(*) from mask")
DataFrame[count(1): bigint]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark operations like sql() do not process anything by default. You need to add .show() or .collect() to get results.